# Freenas cannot mount NFS

Tags: freebsd, nfs, nas

Today I installed FreeNas 9.2.1.8 and now I am trying to set up a NFS.
First I created a Volume with the volume manager. Then I created a dataset.

Now I want to set up a NFS for this dataset.

So I go to share, add UNIX(NFS) share, as mount point I select the path of my created dataset.
As mapalluser and mapallgroup I select nouser and nogroup scince I changed the permission of the dataset to it.

As a final step I have gone to services and switchen on NFS.

When I now try to mount the nfs on Ubuntu 13.10 with

```
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.5:/mnt/Storage/NFS /home/tm/freenas/
```

It says mount.nfs Connection timed out

On the FreeNAS i got an message: rpcb_unset failed.

Does someone know what the problem here is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I solved the problem appearently I had to add my client to the host name database of my freenas server. The Setting can be found at Network Settings-> Global Configuration

And then I add it like:

192.168.1.4 clientmachinename

Comment: did this, didnt solve anything. How do you get verbose output from mount?

Comment: Also no dice for me (TrueNAS and Manjaro)

Comment: This answer is from 2017 with a FreeNAS 9.2.x. I guess this won't apply for up to date versions